# Expanding table cell on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table and in the last column on the right, I had management links for the data in the row.  I now have to add more functions and have decided to replace the text 'edit', 'delete' ... with icons to save space, but it still will not be enough room.. What I would like to do is have it so that the last column has a single icon that when the person hovers over it will expand the cell to the left to reveal all of the function icons available for that record, without expanding the table columns for all of the other rows.. I have seen this done only once, but I can't remember where...

Thanks

Here is the Code I found, but the bottom  never has the border changed on :hover

```
body {
  margin: 0
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc
}

.tHead,
.tRow {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}

.tCell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative
}

.tHead .tCell {
  background: #ccc;
}

.tRow:hover .tCell {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-color: #000;
}

.tRow .tCell:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.tRow:hover + .tRow .tCell {
  border-color: #000;
}

.tRow .tCell:first-child {
  width: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: -6px;
}

.menu:before {
  top: -12px;
}

.actions {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -19px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 28px;
}

.tCell:hover .menu:before,
.tCell:hover .menu:after,
.tCell:hover .menu {
  background: #000
}

.tCell:hover .actions {
  display: block
}

.tRow:hover .tCell:first-child:hover:before,
.tRow:hover .tCell:first-child:hover ~ .tCell:before {
  display: block;
}

<div class="table">
  <div class="tHead">
    <div class="tCell"></div>
    <div class="tCell">Name</div>
    <div class="tCell">Age</div>
    <div class="tCell">Gender</div>
    <div class="tCell">Job Profile</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Kelly</div>
    <div class="tCell">28</div>
    <div class="tCell">Female</div>
    <div class="tCell">Web Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow hovered">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span>
      <span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Jack

    </div>
    <div class="tCell">32</div>
    <div class="tCell">Male</div>
    <div class="tCell">Java Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">
      Janaya
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">26</div>
    <div class="tCell">Female</div>
    <div class="tCell">.Net Developer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tRow ">
    <div class="tCell"><span class="menu"></span><span class="actions">
      <a href="#">Edit</a> |
      <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tCell">Jim</div>
    <div class="tCell">24</div>
    <div class="tCell">Male</div>
    <div class="tCell">Full Stack Developer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide your existing work on this, and any image of the output

Comment: use `:hover` selector to expand the column width. and as suggested by Lakindu, please provide your code so we the same understanding of what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in vanilla CSS, if the example below is what you need.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.lastcell {
  max-width: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}

.lastcell:hover {
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td class="lastcell">Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td class="lastcell">Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td class="lastcell">Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will expand the row if text length is more than width

css:

```
 td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.expandcell{
  max-width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}

.expandcell:hover {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td class="expandcell">Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3 Icon4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td class="expandcell">Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td class="expandcell">Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```